# Evaluating $\int \left(\frac{3}{5} - \frac{8}{x}\right) \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am unsure how to get the antiderivative of

$$f(x) = 
\frac3
5
 − 
\frac8
x$$

I know the answer is $-8\ln(|x|) + C + \frac{3x}{5} $ as it says in my textbook.

But I am unsure how I get something like $\ln(x)$ in the answer? Could someone guide me through this? I am totally lost as for other antiderivatives I have no problem but this stuns me.

Comment: Is it because the 8 is over an x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: there is not such thing as "**the** antiderivative of $f(x)$". There are generally infinitely many different functions that are antiderivatives of $f(x)$. What you can talk about is either "the family of antiderivatives" or "the most general antiderivative", or else "**an** antiderivative". It seems clear you are looking for "the most general antiderivative."

Remember that the **derivative** of $\ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. And the derivative of $kf(x)$ 
with $k$ a constant is $kf'(x)$.

So to get a derivative equal to $-\frac{8}{x} = -8\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, you can take $-8f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a function whose derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$. For example.... $\ln(x)$.

(In fact, the *most general* function whose derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x|+C$, because $(\ln(-x))' = \frac{1}{-x}(-x)' = \frac{1}{x}$, using the Chain Rule.)

So we can, and should, take $-8\ln|x|$ to get the $-\frac{8}{x}$ part of the most general antiderivative. For $\frac{3}{5}$, we can take $\frac{3}{5}x$. And finally, a sum of antiderivatives is an antiderivative of a sum because the derivative of a sum is the sum of antiderivatives; so we take the sum of the two parts, and add the constant to get the general antiderivative. We have:
$$\underbrace{\frac{3}{5}x}_{\text{antiderivative of }\frac{3}{4}} -\underbrace{8\ln|x|}_{\text{antiderivative of }\frac{8}{x}} + C.$$

Comment: Oh alright i get it because $1/x$ would also be as ln(x)

Comment: The most general such function is not $\ln|x|+C$ but (if we're dealing only with _real_ variables) $\ln|x|+\begin{cases} A & \text{if }x>0,\\ B & \text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fact the derivative is linear $$\left( \color{orange}{k}\cdot \color{purple}{f(x)}+\color{orange}{j}\cdot \color{blue}{g(x)}\right)'=\color{orange}{k}\cdot\color{purple}{f'(x)}+\color{orange}{j}\cdot\color{blue}{g'(x)}$$

You seem to know that

$$(x)'=1$$

$$(\log x)'=\dfrac 1 x$$

Then, using the above, can you find a primitive of

$$f(x)=\frac 3 5 \cdot \color{red}{1}+(-8)\cdot \color{red}{\frac 1 x}\text{ ? }$$

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x|$. You can break up the antiderivatives by addition, subtraction, or you can pull scalar multiples out to the front. Since $-\dfrac{8}{x}$ is just $-8 \cdot \dfrac{1}{x}$, the antiderivative is $-8 \ln|x| + C$.